# How to limit number of occurences of a character in HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, input

How can I limit how the number of occurrences of *a period* (for example) *to only 1* in a textbox in HTML? I am wanting to creating a textbox that only accepts numbers and **only 1 period**, to help prevent errors. I am using the HTML element `input` and am using JavaScript (please no JQuery).

Comment: how about you use input `type="number"`? but what you would need to do is listen for keydown events and cancel. Plenty of questions on here about it if you search.

Comment: You can use regex to find occurance of period and ..if it's more than one , you can show error.. or can also remove period from text input

Comment: @epascarello I am using `type="number"`

Comment: @UchitKumar I would like to simply prevent the period, perhaps removing it would work. I just don't know regex

Comment: Add event listener onKeyDown  to input field 
Read text inside input field. 
Split text by "." 
If splitted array length is greater than 2 you have new period. 
Now remove last charector of input text. 
Set this new text as text of input feild.

Comment: @UchitKumar I suppose that would work, but I don't know how to put it together

Answer (score 1):

**1. Allows only numbers without any limitation to periods or decimal points.**

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 &&
    (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input id="textChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="textChar">
```

**2. Allows only decimal numbers with only up to one decimal point and one period**

setTimeout(..., 0) is the way to execute the function after the value of the field has already been modified.

```js
document.write('<input id="inputField" onkeyup="run(this)" />');

function run(field) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var regex = /\d*\.?\d?/g;
    field.value = regex.exec(field.value);
  }, 0);
}
```

**3. Allows only decimal numbers with no limit in decimal points but only one period**

```js
document.getElementById('reg').onkeypress = function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode === 46 && this.value.split('.').length === 2) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="reg">
```

Comment: For this to be an accepted answer, it needs to result in no more than 1 period being allowed in the text box. I already figured out how to allow only numbers and periods, now I want to limit how many periods can be added.

Comment: Hi, check the edited section, It only allows one period

Comment: interesting, it only allows one decimal place. But good job on only allowing 1 period. Could you alter it so there isn't a limit on how many decimal places can exist?

Comment: great. so you don't want a limit on your decimal places? is it?

Comment: Yes. No limit on the decimal places

Comment: Did you test the code to make sure it works? I am able to have multiple periods.

Comment: check the last snippet. you can run the snippet and see. Period means you can keep only one dot in the input fields right?

Answer (score -2):

You could use a Regular expression but it is easier to split the string and count the length. Greater than two means you have two periods:

```
 "Uno. Dos.".split('.').length  #3
 "Uno. Dos".split('.').length  #2
```

Comment: Could you explain this more?

Comment: You didn't post any code so I my response shows the easiest way to count the number of colons.